# Select articles from distinct categories

Tags: mysql

I have a table with some articles named "articles" with the following columns&rows

```
id - category -  title - content - date
1 - 1 - my title - my content - time here
2 - 2 - my title - my content - time here
3 - 1 - my title - my content - time here
4 - 1 - my title - my content - time here
5 - 3 - my title - my content - time here
6 - 1 - my title - my content - time here
7 - 2 - my title - my content - time here
8 - 3 - my title - my content - time her
9 - 4 - my title - my content - time here
10 - 4 - my title - my content - time here
```

I need to select 2 distinct articles only from categories 1,2 and 3

My code so far is:

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE category IN ('1', '2', '3') ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 6
```

Comment: So what's wrong with your code?  Seems pretty correct, actually.  If you only want 2 articles, change your LIMIT to 2.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
SELECt  *
FROm    articles a
WHERE   category IN ('1', '2', '3')
AND     ID IN   (
                    SELECT  ID
                    FROM    articles
                    WHERE   category = a.category
                    ORDER BY date DESC 
                    LIMIT 2
                )
```

Comment: Hi .. I think we are very close .. I got this error : This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery

Answer (score 0):

Just replace you limit from 6 to 2 your code works fine  :

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE category IN ('1', '2', '3') ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 2;
```